# Set tab active when an Activity loads for the first time (Android SlidingTabLayout)

Tags: pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tablayout

Using [SlidngTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)
, i'm not able to set the first tab as active when my activity loads for the first time. Once i click on it, it works fine. However, i need my first tab to be automatically selected when the activity starts the first time

Answer (score 0):

Inside SlidingTabLayout.java i modified the InternalViewPagerListener this way,

So basically, inside `onPageScrolled` method, i did this.

```
 if (position == 0)
                selectedTitle.setSelected(true);
            else
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(0).setSelected(false);
```

Done! Happy coding :)